# Gulp is taking ages to execute tasks

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to give Gulp a try for the first time and can't figure out why is taking so long in loading packages and running tasks, about 48 seconds every time. Not sure how many packages are the average, but I think I need all of them. I've been trying to improve the performance by following some examples but I'm stuck in the same place.
I'd really appreciate any piece of advice!
This is my **gulpfile.js**:

```
            var gulp = require('gulp'),
            runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
            templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
            sass = require('gulp-sass'),
            autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
            rename = require("gulp-rename")
            browserify = require('browserify'),
            concat = require('gulp-concat'),
            addStream = require('add-stream'),
            source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
            buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
            imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
            browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
            reload = browserSync.reload,
            ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
            uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
            jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
            htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier'),
            del = require('del');


            function templates() {
                return gulp.src('./app/views/**/*.html')
                    .pipe(templateCache({
                                module: 'portfolio'
                            }));
            }

            gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
              return del.sync('dist/assets/');
            });

            gulp.task('jshint', function() {
                 return gulp.src('./app/js/**/*.js')
                    .pipe(jshint())
                    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
            });

            gulp.task('browserify', function() { 

                    return  browserify('./app/app.js')
                    .bundle()
                    .pipe(source('main.js'))
                    .pipe(buffer())
                    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
                    .pipe(addStream.obj(templates()))
                    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
                    .pipe(uglify())
                    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/js/'))
            });

            gulp.task('sass', function() {
                return gulp.src('./app/css/main.scss')
                    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
                    .pipe(autoprefixer())
                    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
                    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/css'))
            });

            gulp.task('images', function() {
                return gulp.src('./app/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}')
                .pipe(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/img'))
            });

            gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
               gulp.src('./app/css/fonts/**/*.*')
               .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/fonts'));
            });

            gulp.task('copy-index-html', function() {
                gulp.src('./app/index.html')
                .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
            });

            gulp.task('serve', function() {
                browserSync({
                    server: {
                        baseDir: './dist'
                    }
                });

                gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', ['browserify', reload]);
                gulp.watch('app/css/**/*.scss', ['sass', reload]);
                gulp.watch('app/views/**/*.html', [reload]);
            });

            gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
                browserSync.reload();
            });

            gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
              runSequence('clean:dist',  'jshint', ['browserify', 'sass', 'images','copy-index-html','copyfonts'], 'serve', callback);
            });
```

[Gulp performance (image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJIk4.jpg)

Comment: Is there one task in particular that's taking too long? Or by "loading packages" do you mean `npm install` is taking too long?

Comment: Thanks! What I was refering to with 'loading packages' was when they are required in the gulpfile.js. It looks as if the browserify task is taking longer than the other ones (16sec), but even after that it still takes a while.

Comment: I've just realised that the default task is finishing after 51sec

Comment: So the `browserify` task is only taking 16 seconds of that 51 total second though? Is that the slowest task?

Comment: I edited my question and included a link to an image, which is a screenshot of the console, below the code. I'm learning on the go how Gulp works and how to asses the performance. Now, I've noticed the imagemin task is taking even longer than the browserify one. Hope this added information helps to clarify the scenario. Thanks